# Is there a way that I can open a form and set the cursor in a specific field?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have about 53 long text boxes (Terms & Conditions) that may be used to populate a purchase order contract. I want the user to be able to click on a checkbox in a master form that lists all the clauses and generates a report that only lists the Ts and Cs that are checked. How do I tell Access to include or exclude the text field?

An engineer who may not be familiar with the nature and content of the legal language needs to indicate which clauses need review in a systematic fashion.  It would be very good if the input form opened with the cursor located in the Purchase Order box.

The form opens successfully, and a message box directing the user to change the PO text field initiates successfully. If I can ensure that the first thing the user does is change the PO number I am in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property *Tab order* of the PurchaseOrder textbox to 0.

If it is empty and needs to be filled, cancel the update if it is not filled in:

```
Private Sub PurchaseOrder_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Cancel = IsNull(Me!PurchaseOrder.Value)

End Sub
```

You may have to put the same code line in the *BeforeUpdate* event of the form.

Comment: Thanks , I did not consider that setting the Tab Order could be a simple solution.